# Upsert and Remove Atomicity MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

is there any design pattern to ensure that document is always upsert/updated?

For example,

```
db.people.update(
   { name: "Andy", approved: false },
   {
      name: "Andy",
      rating: 1,
      score: 1,
      approved: true,
   },
   { upsert: true })

db.people.remove(
   { name: "Andy", approved: false },
```

So assume that these two operations occurred concurrently then these following cases can happen:

1. Removed happened first, So the query on update will fail and the
   document will be upserted.
2. Update happened first, So in this case removed will no be able to remove as the query will fail.
3. Update query happened first and succeeded, then remove happened, in this
   case MongoDB will attempt to update an empty document. End result
   will be no document created.

How can I prevent case 3 from happening? Case 1 and 2 is intended. The end goal is to always have to document created when User click update button. I know that update operation is atomic, but I don't think update with and upsert is atomic because of the following statement from MongoDB.

*Consider when multiple clients issue the following update with upsert: true at the same time:If all update() operations complete the query portion before any client successfully inserts data, and there is no unique index on the name field, then each update operation may result in an insert.*

We have Query of the Update as (Q), we have the update/upsert as (U). Another atomic operation is removed(R),

1. Case 1: QUR -> Can't remove (Document Exists)
2. Case 2: QRU -> Upserted (Document Exists)
3. Case 3: RQU -> No update (No document)
4. Case 4: UQR -> Not possible
5. Case 5: URQ -> Not possible
6. Case 6: RUQ -> Not possible

Comment: why do you need to remove the document ? your update with upsert if there is no document it will insert it and if there is matching document it will replace with this doc `{
      name: "Andy",
      rating: 1,
      score: 1,
      approved: true,
   }`

Comment: Hi, the use case is this. Worker send a request form for approval. Work can delete the form and Admin can approve it. I want admin to be the "winner" that is even if worker happen to remove at that instance when admin press approve, the document should appear any way. And your answer seem to be point to Case 1 /2 not case 3.

Comment: If you want the admin to win, then maybe you'll have to save operations within a queue.